# How to print a variable with Requests and JSON

Tags: python, json, object, python-requests, nonetype

I've been programming an application that pulls information from an online API, and I need some help with it.

I'm using requests, and my current code is as follows

```
myData = requests.get('theapiwebsitehere.com/thispartisworking')
myRealData = myData.json()
x = myRealData['data']['playerStatSummaries']['playerStatSummarySet']['maxRating']
print x
```

I then get this error

```
myRealData = myData.json()                                                                                                                      
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I want to be able to get to the variable maxRating, and print it out, but I can't seem to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you "print myData" after .get() ?  I guess the get isn't returning what you think it should (seems to return None).  Not very familiar with requests.  Also can you post some real code (that URL won't work).

Answer (score 23):

Two things, first, make sure you are using the latest version of `requests` (its 1.1.0); in previous versions `json` is not a method but a property.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/burhankhalid')
>>> r.json['name']
u'Burhan Khalid'
>>> requests.__version__
'0.12.1'
```

In the latest version:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'1.1.0'
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/burhankhalid')
>>> r.json()['name']
u'Burhan Khalid'
>>> r.json
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>
```

But, the error you are getting is because your URL isn't returning valid json, and you are trying to call on `None`, what is returned by the property:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
>>> r.json # Note, this returns None
>>> r.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In conclusion:

1. Upgrade your version of `requests` (`pip install -U requests`)
2. Make sure your URL returns valid JSON

Comment: Yeap, old version of Requests was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly is myData actually returning anything?

If it is then you can try the following rather than work with the .json() function

Import the Json package and use the Json loads function on the text.

```
import json
newdata = json.loads(myData.text())
```

Comment: requests already decodes the json into python objects, another reason to love it.

Comment: Yes but services sometimes return the Json with the wrong headers I've found this secondary approach a good fall back